# Qt SQLite Insert doesn't work —— The table is still empty after do INSERT

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

At first,there is only one table in my database... and all the operations like INSERT, SELECT works well,then I add another table but I didn't change my code of operations on first table...
then when I do INSERT,the first table turn out to be still empty.
here is the table schema:

```
QString CreateHistoryTable="CREATE TABLE History("
                        "hist_code VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,"
                        "input_data TEXT NOT NULL,"
                        "output_data TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

here is the CREATE code:

```
void CreateHistory(){
    if(!db.isOpen())
        db.open();
    // judge if table 'History' is existed. IMPORTANT.
    bool isTableExist = query.exec(QString("select count(*) from sqlite_master where type='table' and name='History';")                                   );
    if(!isTableExist)
    {
        if (!query.exec(CreateHistoryTable))
            QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Create History Table Error"),
                                  query.lastError().text());
        query.finish();
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

and the table is created properly as I can see in SQLitemanager..
then the INSERT operation function:

```
QString Insert_History="INSERT INTO History 
                     (hist_code,input_data,output_data) "
                    "VALUES (:hist_code,:input_data,:output_data);";

    void InsertHistory(){
        if(!db.isOpen())
            db.open();
        query.prepare(Insert_History);
        InputToString input2str(in_temp);
        OutputToString output2str(out_temp);
        int num=QueryRunTimes();
        QString histcode=QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")+QString::number(num,10);
        query.bindValue(":hist_code",histcode);
        query.bindValue(":input_data",input2str.getAll());
        query.bindValue(":output_data",output2str.getAll());
        if (!query.exec())
                QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Insert History Error"),
                                      query.lastError().text());
        query.finish();
    }
```

after call this function,the table is still empty...but if I do specific INSERT like:

```
query.exec("INSERT INTO History (hist_code,input_data,output_data) "
                        "VALUES ('1234','aaaaa','bbbbbbb';");
```

It works well,which really confused me......

Comment: To save the instance of table after inserting values, you have to call `commit`. This can solve your problem.

Comment: It still makes no effect... strange right...

Comment: This is not a [mcve]; provide one if you expect useful answers instead of shots in the dark.